# VBA: (Run Time Error 424: Object Required) Proposal Automation

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to automate my proposal but every time I run the below script I get "run time error 424 object required". So this script is supposed to get data from my PowerPoint document and bring into my excel file. Any idea what may be wrong?

```
Dim ppapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pppres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Sub getshapedata()
'On Error GoTo line1
Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation
Dim shapeslide
Dim shapename
Dim shapetext
Dim nextrow

shapeslide = ppapp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
shapename = ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name
shapetext = pppres.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text
friendlyname = InputBox("Insert Friendly Name for " & shapetext, "Friendly Name", "")

nextrow = Sheet1.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheet1.Range("a" & nextrow) = shapeslide
Sheet1.Range("b" & nextrow) = shapename
Sheet1.Range("c" & nextrow) = shapetext
Sheet1.Range("d" & nextrow) = friendlyname

'Exit Sub
'line1:
'MsgBox "No item selected"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please also explain which line gives you the error.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon's suggestion is excellent. Also, make sure that a shape is actually selected in the open PPT presentation, else this line will fail:  shapename = ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the VBA project has a reference to the PowerPoint type libary (it wouldn't compile otherwise), then the supplied code produces error 424 at the first reference to `Sheet1` given:

- Missing `Option Explicit` at the top of the module
- Missing `Sheet1` module in the host workbook document

Adding `Option Explicit` at the top of the module would move the run-time error to compile-time, because if there's no `Sheet1` module then the `Sheet1` identifier isn't defined.

Find the worksheet module you mean to work with in the *Project Explorer* toolwindow (Ctrl+R), then make sure its `(Name)` property (press F4 if the *Properties* toolwindow isn't shown) says `Sheet1`:

[image: Worksheet module properties]

Consider using [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba) (free & open-source add-in for the VBIDE; I manage this project), its *code inspections* feature would have helped pick up the problems ahead of code compilation - in this instance, static code analysis is warning about several undeclared variables and many other "beginner traps":

[image: Rubberduck inspection results in OP's code]

Comment: Thank you! Let me give this a try!